# Running C# project from Visual Studio has different behavior from executables

Tags: c#, regex, executable, visual-studio-debugging

I made a regex parser, among the various functionalities you can also see a `DataGridView` populated with capturing groups with their numbers and pattern. According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#matched-subexpressions):

> Captures that use parentheses  are numbered automatically from left to right based on the order of the opening parentheses in the regular expression, starting from one. The capture that is numbered zero is the text matched by the entire regular expression pattern.

Now if I run the application from VIsual Studio I get what I'm expecting to see while running the executables generated in folders \bin\Debug or \bin\Release the order of some groups is wrong. See the picture below. The pattern used in the example is `^([^$]*(\$[^$]*\$)*[^$]*(\$[^$]*))([AB])(([^$]*\$)[^$]*(\$[^$]*\$)*[^$]*)$`.

Why does this happen and how can I fix it?
[image]

EDIT: SOLVED The original project was compiled with .Net 4.0, I recompiled with version 4.5 and now works well.

Comment: Is there some reason you did not post the code that populates the grid?

Comment: The actual regex did not change and produces the same results when run. So, lets start with that premise. After that, it's something in your code that parses these nested parens.

Comment: Note that the numbering of capture groups when the actual regex is run can vary based on if you turned off named capture group counting and/or if you set the counting to _"Named groups last"_. Still, it's moot point since that's not what your post is about.

Comment: See [how to create a minimal sample](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Maybe you can share a simple sample like what comments above suggests.

Comment: The code used to populate the grid is a bit long and the one used for parsing the groups (to being able to get the pattern with respect to the group number/name) is a way longer function I wrote in another dll where I basically have rewritten how groups (and what kind of groups) are parsed by C# following the official doc. Now I don't get how it is possible that the executable run from VS works while the compiled ones (debug and release) in my bin folder don't.

Comment: What's the result if you start without debugging in VS several times? Same result like the pic1? And what's the result if you run the bin\debug\xx.exe several times, still same result like pic2?

Comment: Solved! The original project was compiled with .Net 4.0, I recompiled with version 4.5 and now works well, thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original project was compiled with .Net 4.0, I recompiled with version 4.5 and now works well.

Comment: Hi friend, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer later and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)